# Is there a "Parallels Desktop" for Ubuntu?

Tags: parallels

I want to use "Parallels Desktop" in Ubuntu.

I did some searching and have found the archive *Parallels.tgz*.
But I'm not sure if this is the right one.

How can I check whether I downloaded the correct archive and how shall I proceed?